# Editing text content for Sampledata.json

Tags: c#, development-environment, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating windows phone 8.1 app using hub template. In the sampledata.json page, I can't edit the contents the way I want to. It only allows me to write in a linear form but I can't make a list, Heading or continue a new text on another line. For example:

```
 { 
  "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-1",
  "Title": "Tiger Nuts Juice",
  "Subtitle": "Prep Time:1hr30mins",
  "ImagePath": "Tiger Nuts Juice1.png",
  "Description" : "Item Description: Pellentesque porta, mauris quis  neque tortor ac erat.",
    "Content" : "I can only write in a linear form just like this. The moment I press enter I'll get an error"},
  {
```

And this is what I get when I run the app:

An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Can anyone help me display the text on the console in a list form?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add newlines to the JSON because that's invalid JSON.
If you want to edit your data and see those changes with the markup you add, don't use JSON.

You could make the `Content` a new object which contains an enumeration of content that you want to see.